# What are some of the problems that arise from introducing too many axioms?

Tags: logic, axioms

From [Mathigon](https://mathigon.org/world/Axioms_and_Proof):

> If there are too many axioms, you can prove almost anything, and mathematics would also not be interesting.

I don't understand this. Why does introducing more axioms cause a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how rigorous that statement is meant to be.  But if one of your axioms contradicts another, every proposition is provable.  That's a big problem.

It's not as if mathematicians spend a lot of time debating whether there are too many axioms or too few.  But there are some notable exceptions.  For thousands of years mathematicians tried to prove that [Euclid's fifth postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) followed from the others.  As it turned out, eliminating that axiom revealed beautiful noneuclidean geometries, totally consistent with the other four postulates.  So adopting a framework with fewer axioms led to many more theorems.

Also, as the article points out, the Axiom of Choice is a famous axiom of set theory.  It seems “obvious” on its face, and there seems to be no reason to adopt it as an axiom.  And yet...it gives us such counter-intuitive theorems as the [Banach-Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox).  But we can't have one without the other.